# OWLAPI: converting OWLOntology object into .owl files

Tags: owl

anyone could help me solve this task?
I need to get an .owl file (possibly specifying the syntax) from an OWLOntology object.
Thanks.

Edit: after using the code below, I got this exception:
 "org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLStorerNotFoundException: Could not find an ontology storer which can handle the format: OWL Functional Syntax". I have tried to search for a solution. So far I have found none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyManager.html#saveOntology-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDocumentFormat-java.io.OutputStream-) and/or [examples](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java) are always a good source ...

```
OWLOntologyManager::saveOntology(OWLOntology ontology, OWLDocumentFormat ontologyFormat, OutputStream outputStream)
```

```java
OWLOntologyManager manager = ...
...
OWLOntology ontology = ...
...
manager.saveOntology(ontology, 
                     new RDFXMLDocumentFormat(), 
                     new FileOutputStream(new File("/PATH/TO/FILE")));
```

Comment: i am getting this:  "org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLStorerNotFoundException: Could not find an ontology storer which can handle the format: OWL Functional Syntax"
by putting the functional syntax and the instruction: "manager.saveOntology(ontology, format, new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/tommy/Desktop/tbox_examples/exampleOWLAPI.owl")))", where that file name is of a not existing file (i suppose it is created immediately)

Comment: it is happening also with Turtle, RDFXML, OWLXML syntaxes

Comment: sorry, i see the file is being created, but it is empty

Comment: How do you use the OWL API? All necessary libraries have to be in the Java classpath.

Comment: I have put the "org.semanticweb.owlapi" jar in my eclipse project. But now i see there are two imports that seem not to come from this library. They are:
    import uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryImpl;
    import uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl;

Comment: That is not enough information. From where do you load which version of the OWL API? And which file? Please provide the link.

Comment: from here: https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%3A%22net.sourceforge.owlapi%22+AND+a%3A%22owlapi-api%22+AND+v%3A%225.1.2%22&a=owlapi-api

Comment: I don't know this site, but I'd strongly recommend downloading releases from the corresponding project page, not some 3rd party distributor. [Here](https://github.com/owlcs/releases) are releases, to get latest version 5.1.2 use [this link](https://github.com/owlcs/releases/raw/master/owlapi/5/owlapi-distribution-5.1.2.jar)

Comment: Downloaded, path built, but still nothing changes.. same exception

Comment: I have just solved the problem, thank you very much!